# Set pdf viewer options when displaying a base64 encoded pdf in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

After downloading a pdf as a base64 string with a request, I want to open a new tab and display the pdf with the "fit screen" option enabled.

The iframe code, where `pdf` is the base64 string:

```
var win = window.open('', '', '');
win.document.write(`
  <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}" width=100% height=100%></iframe>
`);
```

[This answers how to adjust settings with a filename as src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934796/540352):

```
<iframe src="filename.pdf#view=FitH"></iframe>
```

Unfortunately, `src="base64string#view=FitH"` doesn't work. Any way to still accomplish this?

Comment: What is purpose of using `<iframe>` at new `window`? How does `#view=FitH` affect rendered `.pdf`?

Comment: In the actual code, it also writes some tags and css to the window [to avoid double scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758732/how-to-get-rid-of-the-double-scroll-bar-problem-when-using-an-iframe)

Comment: You can substitute `Blob URL` for `data URI` to append fragment identifier to URL. Not certain how to check if `#view=FitH` is being applied, though the fragment identifier will be concatenated at resulting `Blob URL`.

Comment: @Laoujin Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: i found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371246/data-uri-hash-parameters-hide-pdf-toolbar-for-data-uri

Comment: @Jonathan Armando Rojas Lopez thanks for the solution, I got it working, but not with the `#view=fitH` (all the other params from that answer seems to be working though). Was there something you had to do specifically to view=fitH ?